# Understanding filtration argument

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, accessible-categories

I'm trying to read the proof of Theorem 3.1 in [Cellular Categories and Stable Independence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05691). In the proof ii) $\implies$ iii), the author uses filtrations to proceed with the argument. I'm having some trouble understanding why the conclusion holds, where the author claims we can express an arrow as a certain transfinite composition. Below I lay some definitions to talk about the proof.

**Def:** We call an object filtrable if it can be expressed as the colimit of a chain of objects of lower presentability rank (the smallest presentability cardinal), and such chain also has a length below the presentability rank.

**Def:** A cellular category is a pair $(\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{M})$ where $\mathcal{K}$ is a cocomplete category and $\mathcal{M}$ a set of morphisms, called cellular, containing all isomorphisms and closed under pushouts and transfinite compositions.

We can define a subcategory $\mathcal{K}_\mathcal{M}$ of cellular arrows, but this subcategory needn't have pushouts since the induced arrow needn't be cellular. To that end, we define:

**Def:** A commutative square
[image]

is called cellular if the induced arrow from the pushout of the span $C \leftarrow A \rightarrow B$, $P \to D$, is cellular.

---

The collection of cellular square is almost a stable independence relation, and the main theorem aims to charaterize when it is in terms of the category being combinatorial.

**Def:** $(\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{M})$ is called combinatorial if $\mathcal{M} = \operatorname{Cof}(X)$ (cofibrantly generated), that is, $\mathcal{M}$ is the closure under retracts (in the category of arrows), pushouts and transfinite compositions of some set $X$.

We have

> Theorem 3.1 (part of):
> (ii) The cellular squares form an stable independence relation in $\mathcal{K}_M$
> implies
> (iii) $(\mathcal{K}, \mathcal{M})$ is combinatorial

From an earlier article it is know that (ii) amounts to the subcategory $\mathcal{K}_{\mathcal{M}, \downarrow}$ (which is a subcategory of arrows whose morphisms give cellular squares) being accessible and closed under directed colimits. This allows us to express every object as a retract of an object with a filtration there, and that is how the argument proceeds.

The authors basically take $\lambda$ s.t. both $\mathcal{K}$, $\mathcal{K}_{\mathcal{M}, \downarrow}$ are $\lambda$-accessible and almost well-$\lambda$-filtrable (every object with rk $\geq \lambda$ admits a retract in a filtrable object), then we prove by induction that for every $\mu$, $\mathcal{M}_{\mu^+} \subseteq \operatorname{cof}(\mathcal{M}_\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{M}_\mu$ is the set of arrows in $\mathcal{M}$ with $\mu$-presentable (co)domain.

The ideia is basically as follows: for any $h = h_0: K_0 \to L$ in $\mathcal{M}_{\mu^+}$, we WLOG assume $h_0$ is filtrable (as $\operatorname{cof}$ is retract-closed), then take a filtration

[image]

then take a pushout to obtain $h_1$:

[image]  

Noting that by induction hypothesis and pushout-closure, $h_{0,1} \in \operatorname{cof}(\mathcal{M}_\lambda)$.  

Now, we take a filtration (?) for $h_1$ above $t_{01}$ (this just seems to be presentability factoring),
[image]

then we repeat the same thing we did, but taking a pushout along $t_{1, 1}$ instead. This proccess is the successor proccess in transfinite induction, while the limit proccess is just a colimit (on the $h_{i, i+1}$). Doing this, we obtain a $\operatorname{cf}{(\mu)}$-chain. Then, since $h = \operatorname{colim}{ h_{i, i+1}}$, and $\operatorname{cof}(\mathcal{M}_\lambda)$ is closed under transfinite inductions, $h$ is there too.

---

First of all,how can $h_1$ be filtrable just like $h_0$? It seemed that $h_1$ was actually supposed to be a retract of such filtrable object, but I don't know if this goes through and why the author would bother with $h_0$ being filtrable in first place.

Most importantly, I can't understand how the conclusion is true, and maybe that helps with the retract part. Of course it makes intuitive sense that $h$ is the contructed transfinite composition, but either I'm missing some cofinality argument with the $t_{0i}$ inclusions and the fact we take pushouts at $t_{i, i}$ or something else. I've tried drawing diagrams but really can't get anything substantial to work, the arrows $t_{0i}$ are vertically chained while the $h_{i, i + 1}$ are horizontally chained, so I can't see how to apply the fact we have $t_{0, i} \to t_{i, i} \to h_{i, i + 1}$ in the construction. Does universality of the pushouts induces universality of our cocone $(h_i: K_i \to L)$? If so, how?

I'd appreciate if someone could assist me in understanding the proof construction, both the filtration assumption on $h_1$ and the overall construction. It needn't be a full blown explanation of the details, just a hint to work out the conclusion, that is, that $K_{\operatorname{cf}{(\mu)}} = L, h_0 = \operatorname{colim}{ h_{i, i+ 1} }$.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Transcribed proof above, which anyone can find in pages 9-10 of the linked article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I understand now how the construction implicitly goes. The ideia is that pushouts induce colimits (hence why we have $h_1$ filtrable), and that's how we proceed with the argument. When taking the first pushout, we get induced colimit diagrams

[image]

We basically glue these $t^\prime_{i, j}$ diagrams together filling the previous spots with identities. That is, at the $i$th row we start the arrow $t^\prime_{i, j}$ diagram, filling the previous rows with identities. This gives us the following diagram (with compatible cocones which are colimits)

[image]

We proceed with this construction by taking colimits at limit steps, then we obtain basically a chain of natural transformations between the diagrams (the row chains) with compatible cocones which are colimit cocones, and we can apply commutativity of colimits

[image]

Then $\operatorname{colim}{D} \implies \operatorname{colim}{c}$ is precisely

[image]